# Primary key requirements

Tags: sql, database-design, primary-key

Is it a good idea to store phone number as a primary key on RDBMS? They are unique to nearly all of us. But my friend suggests it is not a good idea because of the following reasons.

- What if two people in a family share a phone number?
- What if a person does not have a phone number?

What are your insights, please let me know!.

Comment: Additionally: it's not uncommon to **change** your phone number - when you move from one place to another, or if you get a new phone. A primary key **must be** unique and not null, and it **should be** stable (never changes) if ever possible

Comment: Probably not...but it would be good to have an non-unique index on phone number.

Comment: You may have the phone number as a (non unique) *indexed* field and add an autogenerated integer ID as PK

Comment: "what are your insights" is not a valid SO question. See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Presumably you have a definition of "PK" or you wouldn't use the term. Applying it, PK values in a table must be 1:1 with rows. It doesn't even make sense to ask whether values are suitable for PKs without giving a table & the criteria for rows being in it. Obviously if rows are 1:1 with some people in a table then phone numbers are a possible PK for them in it when a phone number maps to just one.  What specific question are you asking where you are stuck?

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be against this idea, generally for reasons:

- It is personally identifiable information and I'd recommend using it with caution if you're bound to GDPR. Some users might ask you to not use their phone numbers. It might later be required to hash or mask part of the phone number, or even completely get rid of it.
- Value depends on user input even it is validated. There are several services which lend you a phone number for validation if you're not in the target country of the validator.
- A schema needs to be defined of the phone number if it will contain country code, parentheses or spaces.
- There should be a validation to prevent duplicates and null values.

In summary it is not a good idea to use a field which has a dependency to external facts. As others mentioned, using an autogenerated identifier for the ID and non-unique index for the phone number seems like a better approach.

Comment: Other important reasons are that it can change over time, different people could share the same phone number, and it might discriminate against certain groups of people who do not regularly use phones.

Answer (score 2):

A phone number certainly can make sense as a key but all depends on what you need to identify and how you intend to use it. There is no general right or wrong answer.

Three very good criteria (but not absolute rules) for choosing and designing keys are: Simplicity, Stability, Familiarity. Phone numbers are simple and familiar enough for many purposes. Whether they are stable enough is probably highly dependent on circumstances. For example you might require all your employees to supply a unique phone number for third-factor authentication but probably it's quite acceptable to change that number occasionally.

Answer (score 1):

what is the purpose of having phone number as primary key, is it to identify a individual? if so one individual can have multiple phone numbers (mobile/home phone) so it is not advisable to use phone number as primary key.
Also your question is right what if a person does not have phone number.

Comment: A person can have more than one passport but you only need one passport number to identify an individual. The same could be true of telephone numbers, under the right circumstances.